# Como inicializar una estructura compuesta con etiquetas json

Tags: json, go

Quiero inicializar una estructura compuesta.
La estructura compuesta tiene etiquetas json, y al ejecutar el programa me muestra algo como lo siguiente:

```
go run struct.go 
# command-line-arguments
./struct.go:23:11: cannot use struct { Lat float32; Lon float32 } literal (type struct { Lat float32; Lon float32 }) as type struct { Lat float32 "json:\"lat\""; Lon float32 "json:\"lon\"" } in field value
```

Alguien que me pueda decir que es lo que me falta o que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

El programa con el que estoy haciendo pruebas es el siguiente:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Document struct {
    Ciudad     string `json:"ciudad"`
    Colonia    string `json:"colonia"`
    Cp         int `json:"cp"`
    Delegacion string `json:"delegacion"`
    Location   struct {
        Lat float32 `json:"lat"`
        Lon float32 `json:"lon"`
    } `json:"location"`
}

func main() {

    d := &Document{
        Ciudad: "xxxx xxxx",
        Colonia: "yyyy yyyy",
        Cp: 3333,
        Delegacion: "zzzz zzzz",
        Location: struct {
            Lat float32
            Lon float32
        }{
            Lat: -111.111, 
            Lon: 111.111,
        },

    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", d)

}
```

Aquí dejo la liga con el programa en la versión playground de go:

https://play.golang.org/p/y2Zb6aVhbT

Answer (score 1):

Buenos días, define tu objeto **Location** fuera del '*struct*' **Document**  y para asignarle valores obvia la parte del código en la que vuelves a definir el objeto Location.

Te quedaría algo así:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Document struct {
    Ciudad     string `json:"ciudad"`
    Colonia    string `json:"colonia"`
    Cp         int `json:"cp"`
    Delegacion string `json:"delegacion"`
    Location   `json:"location"`
}

type Location struct{
    Lat float32 `json:"lat"`
    Lon float32 `json:"lon"`
}



func main() {

    d := &Document{
        Ciudad:     "xxxx xxxx",
        Colonia:    "yyyy yyyy",
        Cp:         3333,
        Delegacion: "zzzz zzzz",
        Location: Location {
            Lat: -111.111,
            Lon: 111.111,
        },
    }

    fmt.Printf("%v", d)

}
```

Y daría la siguiente salida:

> &{xxxx xxxx yyyy yyyy 3333 zzzz zzzz {-111.111 111.111}}

Aquí tienes la demo https://play.golang.org/p/zNQfjQujdh

Espero haberte ayudado.

EDITO: probando un poco más he conseguido la siguiente salida (que creo que es la que deseabas en primer lugar).

> {"ciudad":"xxxx xxxx","colonia":"yyyy yyyy","cp":3333,"delegacion":"zzzz zzzz","location":{"lat":-111.111,"lon":111.111}}

Para ello debes importar **encoding/json** y hacer uso del método **json.Marshal()**

El código es el siguiente:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "encoding/json"

type Document struct {
    Ciudad     string `json:"ciudad"`
    Colonia    string `json:"colonia"`
    Cp         int `json:"cp"`
    Delegacion string `json:"delegacion"`
    Location   `json:"location"`
}

type Location struct{
    Lat float32 `json:"lat"`
        Lon float32 `json:"lon"`
}



func main() {

    d := &Document{
        Ciudad:     "xxxx xxxx",
        Colonia:    "yyyy yyyy",
        Cp:         3333,
        Delegacion: "zzzz zzzz",
        Location: Location {
            Lat: -111.111,
            Lon: 111.111,
        },
    }
    jso,_ := json.Marshal(d)
    fmt.Printf("%v", string(jso))

}
```

Y aquí la demo https://play.golang.org/p/i3Zb8Otysy